# Move from one table to another

Tags: php, mysql, database, move

I need to move some data from a table to a archive table.

Now I do it this way:

```
$sql = 'INSERT INTO history_products 
         SELECT * FROM products WHERE category_id='.$id;
```

And then I delete data from products table.

```
$sql_delete = 'DELETE FROM products WHERE category_id = '.$id;
```

Each product have a unique id.
But I want to make this in a secure way, now even if a row isn't inserted in history_products the row will be deleted from products table. I don't want to delete if insert fails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I expected you have a field called id (ProduktID), which products must have the same id in both tables then, the following should work.

Delete from products where products.id IN (Select history_products.id from history_products)

Comment: This way I think: DELETE FROM products WHERE category_id = $category_id AND products.id IN (SELECT history_products.id from history_products)

Comment: DELETE FROM products WHERE products.category_id = $category_id AND products.id IN (SELECT history_products.id from history_products and history_products.category_id = $category_id) that will make the count of IN set smaller an probably the whole execution a little faster

Comment: Or this way?: DELETE FROM products WHERE products.id IN (SELECT history_products.id FROM history_products WHERE category_id = $category_id) ?

Comment: U are right I had a C&P mistake ;) But I would use the categorie in both Where's

Answer (score 1):

If using unique keys, delete all records from products that have the same keys as those in the history table.

Comment: This means I have to make another select after INSERT to get all the rows inserted?!

Comment: no i think he means what i worte.. use the unique product id which must be same in both tables, in the WHERE Clause of the DELETE

Comment: No SELECT necessary. Just a DELETE WHERE.

Answer (score 1):

```
DELETE FROM products WHERE category_id IN (SELECT category_id FROM history_products)
```

This'd only delete records in the products table where a corresponding record exists in history_products.

Comment: This will still delete records with the same category that were not moved over.

Comment: u are still deleting the whole category... mich approach is going with the productid an delete the ones out of products whose id is in the history table

Comment: Well, change category_id to whatever the primary key field is on both sides - simple enough.